# IIS Client Certificate Mapping Rule not being respected

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am running IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2. I have configured a WebAPI (built on ASP.net) web site to use HTTPS (self-signed) with IIS Client Certificate Mapping for client certificate authentication. I am using the ManyToOneMapping where I have defined one local account to be associated to the client certificate with the incoming request. Furthermore, I have defined a Rule in the mapping so that if the "Subject" field in the certificate contains a certain string then it should allow the request.

Now, when I hit the url in the API application, Firefox prompts me to select the certificate to be used (as expected). And when i select one of the certificates that **does not** contain that string defined in the mapping Rule, the browser is **still** served with the resource. I was expected a forbidden response instead. So, it would appear that the Client Certificate mapping is not working as expected.

As I am new to IIS, I am wondering how I could go about to find out how to troubleshoot this situation. Thanks in advance.

Here is snippet from the applicationhost.config file:

```
<location path="SimpleApi" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="false">
                    <manyToOneMappings>
                        <add name="Authorized Access" description="Some long description" userName="SomeUser" password="[enc:AesProvider:removed:enc]">
                            <rules>
                                <clear />
                                <add certificateField="Subject" certificateSubField="OU" matchCriteria="Admin" />
                            </rules>
                        </add>
                    </manyToOneMappings>
                    <oneToOneMappings />
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="SimpleApi">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility is you have other authentication mechanism enabled for your website and it is simply falling back to that authentication mechanism.

Check the **Authentication** module for your website in IIS and disable all other authentication mechanism.